# webGL/JS - load files

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm creating a little Game Engine while learning webGL and JavaScript, using Components to add functionalities to the GameObjects. Right now I have a GameObject array where I store all the GO, with their components and transform. 
Right now I have 3 components implemented:
 - KeyController: allows to move the GO position with WASD
 - Camera: stores the camera configuration.
 - Renderer: stores mesh, texture and the shader of the GO to render.

**THE PROBLEM IS:** I can load a mesh from an ASE file, with its parser, but it works for 1 object, if I try to load more than 1 file, the previous object loses all the data loaded from the file, so the buffers are empty and can't render the meshes.

[image]

This image shows the console.log from the GO array where you can see the renderer component from the objects 5 and 6, and the vertexNormalBuffer, vertexPositionBuffer, vertexTextureCoordBuffer, that in the object 5 are Object type, and at the object 6 are WebGLBuffer, what are supposed to be.

```
function webGLStart() {
    ...
    for (var i = 3; i < 7; i++){
        objects[i] = new GameObject("crate",[-5+i*3,0.0,-100]);
        var ren1 = new Renderer("box.ase","crate.gif");
        objects[i].addComponent("renderer", ren1);
    }

    ...

    initShaders();
    initTextures();
    initBuffers();

    ...     
}
function initBuffers(){
    for (var i in objects){
        if (objects[i].components.renderer != null){
            objects[i].components.renderer.loadMesh();
        }
    }
}
Renderer.prototype.loadMesh = function() {
    obj = this;
    var format = this.pathMesh.split('.')[1];
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", this.pathMesh);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var options = {};
            options.flipAxis = true;
            obj.initBuffer(Parser.parsers[format].parse(request.responseText,options));
            return obj;
        }
    }
    request.send(null);
}
Renderer.prototype.initBuffer = function(mesh){     
    this.vertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.vertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    this.vertexPositionBuffer.numItems = mesh.vertices.length/3;                

    this.vertexNormalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexNormalBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.normals, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.vertexNormalBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    this.vertexNormalBuffer.numItems = mesh.normals.length/3;

    this.vertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexTextureCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.coords, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.vertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
    this.vertexTextureCoordBuffer.numItems =  mesh.coords.length/2;
}
```

This is the most relevant code to understand what I'm doing, but if you want to check it on the run: http://www.madowen.es/webGL/pruebas.html

As far as I know from JavaScript the problem comes from the way I load the files, but I dont know how to fix that, any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are hitting an async timing issue. Although it is not a good idea to set your request as synchronous because it will hang your browser until the job is done, you can try to add & set the third parameter of request.open to "false" in your loadmesh() function, and your objects will get initialized properly (I saw your cube when setting a breakpoint on your render call). HTH

Comment: Thank you so much, now I have another errors but I think I can fix them (it's about using more than one shader program I guess). This tutorial (http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1523) explains how to use multiple programs.

Comment: It should be possible to solve the asynchronous loading of your meshes data too. Not sure, but maybe trying to delay your initBuffer() call. Good luck